# jQuery UI Tabs INSTANTLY error (AJAX) when I switch to a different tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, error-handling, jquery-tabs

I'm using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/). One of my tabs is loaded via AJAX. I have the `cache` option set to true and **everything works perfectly, except...** when I click on an AJAX tab, then quickly switch to a different tab, the AJAX tab seems to be aborted instantly, and raises an error (with no error text).

As a test, I setup a tab that, on the server had a 2.5 second delay... If I click on the AJAX tab and wait... then the content shows up... but if I switch to a different tab before the 2.5 seconds is up, the `error` event is raised.

**So the question is, How do I prevent the AJAX stuff from being aborted** just because I switched to a different tab?

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you posted your code

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem.  I was going to disabled other tabs until the jax response finishes then reable them until I can find the REAL fix for this.